# Blank line before unordered HTML list in Jasper Report

Tags: java, html, jasper-reports

I'm trying to remove a blank line in an HTML marked up textField. 
I have a band with markup="html":

```
<band height="1" splitType="Stretch">
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="515" height="0"/>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Top" markup="html">
            <font fontName="Arial" pdfFontName="jasper/fonts/ARIAL.TTF"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{input}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
</band>
```

The value of input is:

```
<p>Here is a list</p>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that when I export this it displays like:

[image: Screenshot of pdf that is generated from the jasper file]

If I export this to word there is a blank line between "Here is a list" and the actual list. I have also tried it without the paragraph tags but the result was the same.

I generate the report from java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `<p>` and `<ul>` tags
Then the value of input will be :

```
Here is a list
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
```

That will remove a blank line

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just an extract from [this website](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/styledtext/index.html): The JasperReports proprietary markup language is called styled text and is an XML based format in which the style of any portion of text inside a text element can be changed by embedding that portion inside a <style> tag or other simple HTML tag from the following list:
<b>
<u>
<i>
<font>
<sup>
<sub>
<li>
<br>